# Is there a way to execute a function after a bot is removed from the server in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have tried using the `client.on('guildDelete', () => {remove roles and other things})` , but everytime the bot is removed from my test server it says "Missing Access" (even though my bot has adminstrative privelages on my test server, and all other features work). I am assuming this is because the event is registered after the bot is removed from the server, which would make sense and is why I am tring to find away around that. Any and all help is appreciated.

Full source code: https://github.com/blb7103/sw-bot

Comment: You cannot do this because its too late

Comment: @StarsTracker I understand that, my question is if there are any work arounds for this or another event or function I can use to achieve this.

Comment: It is impossible to remove a guild members roles after they have already left, there is no other event that will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisely what you said -- the event fires when the bot has officially left the server, and therefore cannot access/edit anything within that server.

There are no workarounds to this.

Comment: oh well, worth a try.